# accessible pointer becomes inaccessible in gdb

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I am able to access a memory address in GDB however after sometimes the same location becomes inaccessible. Please, have a look at  printing of pointer *gptr in gdb. It looks weird to me and not sure why. Can anyone explain to me how come this is possible? Is this value time dependent?

```
/home/ubuntu#gdb -p  `pidof e2`
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Attaching to process 1424839
[New LWP 1424840]
[New LWP 1424841]
[New LWP 1424842]
[New LWP 1424843]
[New LWP 1424844]
[New LWP 1424887]
[New LWP 1424888]
[New LWP 1424889]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

warning: Target and debugger are in different PID namespaces; thread lists and other data are likely unreliable.  Connect to gdbserver inside the container.
__pthread_clockjoin_ex (threadid=139701780469504, thread_return=0x0, clockid=<optimized out>, abstime=<optimized out>, block=<optimized out>) at pthread_join_common.c:145
145 pthread_join_common.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) n

Thread 5 "e2" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7f0edbfff700 (LWP 1424843)]
SIwait (gptr=0x56073ee70060) at /home/ubuntu/shardul/nearrt-ric-plt/rmr/src/rmr/si/src/si95/siwait.c:123
123                                     if( (cbptr = gptr->cbtab[SI_CB_DISC].cbrtn) != NULL ) {
(gdb) p *gptr            ------------> value is accessible here
$1 = {magicnum = 219, tplist = 0x7f0ec4001b40, readfds = {__fds_bits = {0 <repeats 16 times>}}, writefds = {__fds_bits = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 281474976710656, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, execpfds = {__fds_bits = {
      0 <repeats 16 times>}}, rbuf = 0x0, cbtab = 0x0, fdcount = 0, flags = 0, tcp_flags = 0, rbuflen = 0, sierr = 0, tp_map = 0x0}
(gdb) p gptr->cbtab[SI_CB_DISC]
No symbol "SI_CB_DISC" in current context.
(gdb) p  SI_CB_DISC
No symbol "SI_CB_DISC" in current context.
(gdb) p  *gptr          --------------> value became inaccessible here. Why?
Cannot access memory at address 0x56073ee70060
```

Just to make a note, the debugged process is running inside a docker container, and we are debugging that process from the host machine instead of inside the container.

output of cat /proc/`pidof e2`/map from inside the docker where this program is running

```
root@e2term-alpha:/opt/e2# cat /proc/23/map
cat: /proc/23/map: No such file or directory
root@e2term-alpha:/opt/e2#
```

output of cat /proc/`pidof e2`/map from host machine where docker container is running

```
/home/ubuntu#cat /proc/1649744/map
cat: /proc/1649744/map: No such file or directory
/home/ubuntu#
```

pmap ouput before crash happend

```
/home/ubuntu#pmap `pidof e2`
1690720:   ./e2 -p config -f config.conf
0000564014268000    220K r---- e2
000056401429f000    868K r-x-- e2
0000564014378000    348K r---- e2
00005640143cf000     52K r---- e2
00005640143dc000    120K rw--- e2
00005640143fa000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
000056401587e000    372K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c4c000000   1036K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c4c103000  64500K -----   [ anon ]
00007f5c54000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c54021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00007f5c58000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c58021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00007f5c5c000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c5c021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00007f5c60000000    296K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c6004a000  65240K -----   [ anon ]
00007f5c66ffe000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00007f5c66fff000   8192K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c677ff000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00007f5c67800000   8192K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c68000000    484K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c68079000  65052K -----   [ anon ]
00007f5c6c30b000    260K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c6c38d000    260K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c6c40f000    260K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c6c491000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00007f5c6c492000   8192K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c6cc92000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00007f5c6cc93000   8192K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c6d493000     16K r---- libresolv-2.31.so
00007f5c6d497000     64K r-x-- libresolv-2.31.so
00007f5c6d4a7000     16K r---- libresolv-2.31.so
00007f5c6d4ab000      4K r---- libresolv-2.31.so
00007f5c6d4ac000      4K rw--- libresolv-2.31.so
00007f5c6d4ad000      8K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c6d4af000      4K r---- libnss_dns-2.31.so
00007f5c6d4b0000     16K r-x-- libnss_dns-2.31.so
00007f5c6d4b4000      4K r---- libnss_dns-2.31.so
00007f5c6d4b5000      4K r---- libnss_dns-2.31.so
00007f5c6d4b6000      4K rw--- libnss_dns-2.31.so
00007f5c6d4b7000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00007f5c6d4b8000   8192K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c6dcb8000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00007f5c6dcb9000   8192K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c6e4b9000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00007f5c6e4ba000   8192K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c6ecba000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00007f5c6ecbb000   8356K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c6f4e4000     12K r---- libnss_files-2.31.so
00007f5c6f4e7000     28K r-x-- libnss_files-2.31.so
00007f5c6f4ee000      8K r---- libnss_files-2.31.so
00007f5c6f4f0000      4K r---- libnss_files-2.31.so
00007f5c6f4f1000      4K rw--- libnss_files-2.31.so
00007f5c6f4f2000     56K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c6f500000      4K r---- libdl-2.31.so
00007f5c6f501000      8K r-x-- libdl-2.31.so
00007f5c6f503000      4K r---- libdl-2.31.so
00007f5c6f504000      4K r---- libdl-2.31.so
00007f5c6f505000      4K rw--- libdl-2.31.so
00007f5c6f506000      4K r---- libicudata.so.66.1
00007f5c6f507000      4K r-x-- libicudata.so.66.1
00007f5c6f508000  27380K r---- libicudata.so.66.1
00007f5c70fc5000      4K r---- libicudata.so.66.1
00007f5c70fc6000      4K rw--- libicudata.so.66.1
00007f5c70fc7000      8K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c70fc9000    404K r---- libicuuc.so.66.1
00007f5c7102e000    916K r-x-- libicuuc.so.66.1
00007f5c71113000    536K r---- libicuuc.so.66.1
00007f5c71199000      4K ----- libicuuc.so.66.1
00007f5c7119a000     72K r---- libicuuc.so.66.1
00007f5c711ac000      4K rw--- libicuuc.so.66.1
00007f5c711ad000      8K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c711af000    932K r---- libicui18n.so.66.1
00007f5c71298000   1524K r-x-- libicui18n.so.66.1
00007f5c71415000    536K r---- libicui18n.so.66.1
00007f5c7149b000      4K ----- libicui18n.so.66.1
00007f5c7149c000     64K r---- libicui18n.so.66.1
00007f5c714ac000      4K rw--- libicui18n.so.66.1
00007f5c714ad000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c714ae000      8K r---- librt-2.31.so
00007f5c714b0000     16K r-x-- librt-2.31.so
00007f5c714b4000      8K r---- librt-2.31.so
00007f5c714b6000      4K r---- librt-2.31.so
00007f5c714b7000      4K rw--- librt-2.31.so
00007f5c714b8000    104K r---- libboost_regex.so.1.71.0
00007f5c714d2000    760K r-x-- libboost_regex.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71590000    136K r---- libboost_regex.so.1.71.0
00007f5c715b2000     20K r---- libboost_regex.so.1.71.0
00007f5c715b7000      4K rw--- libboost_regex.so.1.71.0
00007f5c715b8000     12K r---- libgcc_s.so.1
00007f5c715bb000     72K r-x-- libgcc_s.so.1
00007f5c715cd000     16K r---- libgcc_s.so.1
00007f5c715d1000      4K r---- libgcc_s.so.1
00007f5c715d2000      4K rw--- libgcc_s.so.1
00007f5c715d3000      8K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c715d5000    136K r---- libc-2.31.so
00007f5c715f7000   1504K r-x-- libc-2.31.so
00007f5c7176f000    312K r---- libc-2.31.so
00007f5c717bd000     16K r---- libc-2.31.so
00007f5c717c1000      8K rw--- libc-2.31.so
00007f5c717c3000     16K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c717c7000     52K r---- libm-2.31.so
00007f5c717d4000    668K r-x-- libm-2.31.so
00007f5c7187b000    612K r---- libm-2.31.so
00007f5c71914000      4K r---- libm-2.31.so
00007f5c71915000      4K rw--- libm-2.31.so
00007f5c71916000    600K r---- libstdc++.so.6.0.28
00007f5c719ac000    964K r-x-- libstdc++.so.6.0.28
00007f5c71a9d000    292K r---- libstdc++.so.6.0.28
00007f5c71ae6000      4K ----- libstdc++.so.6.0.28
00007f5c71ae7000     44K r---- libstdc++.so.6.0.28
00007f5c71af2000     12K rw--- libstdc++.so.6.0.28
00007f5c71af5000     12K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c71af8000     24K r---- libpthread-2.31.so
00007f5c71afe000     68K r-x-- libpthread-2.31.so
00007f5c71b0f000     24K r---- libpthread-2.31.so
00007f5c71b15000      4K r---- libpthread-2.31.so
00007f5c71b16000      4K rw--- libpthread-2.31.so
00007f5c71b17000     16K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c71b1b000      8K r---- libz.so.1.2.11
00007f5c71b1d000     68K r-x-- libz.so.1.2.11
00007f5c71b2e000     24K r---- libz.so.1.2.11
00007f5c71b34000      4K ----- libz.so.1.2.11
00007f5c71b35000      4K r---- libz.so.1.2.11
00007f5c71b36000      4K rw--- libz.so.1.2.11
00007f5c71b37000     28K r---- libboost_filesystem.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71b3e000     64K r-x-- libboost_filesystem.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71b4e000     20K r---- libboost_filesystem.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71b53000      4K r---- libboost_filesystem.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71b54000      4K rw--- libboost_filesystem.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71b55000      8K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c71b57000     56K r---- libboost_thread.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71b65000     76K r-x-- libboost_thread.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71b78000     28K r---- libboost_thread.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71b7f000     12K r---- libboost_thread.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71b82000      4K rw--- libboost_thread.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71b83000    300K r---- libboost_log.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71bce000    496K r-x-- libboost_log.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71c4a000    160K r---- libboost_log.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71c72000     40K r---- libboost_log.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71c7c000      4K rw--- libboost_log.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71c7d000    132K r---- libboost_log_setup.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71c9e000    468K r-x-- libboost_log_setup.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71d13000    132K r---- libboost_log_setup.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71d34000     24K r---- libboost_log_setup.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71d3a000      4K rw--- libboost_log_setup.so.1.71.0
00007f5c71d3b000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c71d3c000     12K r---- librmr_si.so.4
00007f5c71d3f000     80K r-x-- librmr_si.so.4
00007f5c71d53000     20K r---- librmr_si.so.4
00007f5c71d58000      4K r---- librmr_si.so.4
00007f5c71d59000      4K rw--- librmr_si.so.4
00007f5c71d5a000     16K r-x-- libmdclog.so.0
00007f5c71d5e000   2044K ----- libmdclog.so.0
00007f5c71f5d000      4K r---- libmdclog.so.0
00007f5c71f5e000      4K rw--- libmdclog.so.0
00007f5c71f5f000      4K r---- libsctp.so.1
00007f5c71f60000      4K r-x-- libsctp.so.1
00007f5c71f61000      4K r---- libsctp.so.1
00007f5c71f62000      4K r---- libsctp.so.1
00007f5c71f63000      4K rw--- libsctp.so.1
00007f5c71f64000      8K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5c71f69000      4K r---- ld-2.31.so
00007f5c71f6a000    140K r-x-- ld-2.31.so
00007f5c71f8d000     32K r---- ld-2.31.so
00007f5c71f96000      4K r---- ld-2.31.so
00007f5c71f97000      4K rw--- ld-2.31.so
00007f5c71f98000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
00007ffdc18de000    144K rw---   [ stack ]
00007ffdc190b000     12K r----   [ anon ]
00007ffdc190e000      4K r-x--   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000      4K --x--   [ anon ]
 total           505736K
/home/ubuntu#
```

Comment: Please show `cat /proc/\`pidof e2\`/map` and `pmap \`pidof e2\``

Comment: @273K when i run cat /proc/`pidof e2`/map it says no such file. why?  however i see pmap output which i have added in main thread......one thing i forgot to mention this process is running in a docker container where its pid is 23 where from host machine where docker is installed its pid is 1649744 and both places i did not find map file under proc. (updated output in main thread)

Comment: `0x56073ee70060` is not in the memory dump. Perhaps because of Docker. Analyzing a crash dump may help.

Comment: @273K at what time i have to take pmap output? before crash when program is running fine or right after the crash?  moreover due to docker limitations core files are not getting generated in my container hence no point in that